# (Ionic) Runtime Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ActionSheetCmp: ([object Object], [object Object],

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Need help resolving runtime issue in ionic app when run ionic serve.

```
Runtime Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ActionSheetCmp: ([object Object], 
[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
```

Have run on android device and get app opening with blank screen.

See this error at the top when try ionic serve in terminal

```
[app-scripts] no-unused-variable is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the 
built-in compiler checks instead.
```

Followed by a bunch of duplicate error variables like this (which normally wouldn't stop running)

```
can't successfully serve app or run on Android:
[app-scripts] [00:00:02]  tslint: ...s/elliotgilford/downloads/elgilford-journal3- 
e4687f538ac4/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 314 
[app-scripts]             Duplicate variable: 'correctPath' 
[app-scripts]      L313:  var currentName = 
imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Bucketjournal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.11",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.12",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.7.1",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "ionic": "^5.4.16",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "native-run": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-renderer": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "session": "^0.1.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "gradle": "^1.2.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Add you actionsheetcomp code here.

Comment: Thanks, I did a search for actionsheetcmp, there are 88 mentions of it across vendor.js and vendor.js.map Don't think I have touched those files though and those files are 70k+ lines of code. Any ideas?